# OpenLayers 4.x DescribeFeatureType to populate a filter menu

Tags: openlayers, wfs, fields-attributes, filter

With OpenLayers 4, I'm trying to get field names from a WFS request (https://localhost:8080/myws?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAME=ms:layername&outputFormat=gml/2.1.2) and parse it into JSON or something else.

I found a solution, but it is for OpenLayers 2 ([example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87979/check-if-property-exists-on-features-in-layer#88032))

Does somebody know if

```
OpenLayers.Format.WFSDescribeFeatureType();
```

will be deployed into OpenLayers 4?

Any other way possible? My goal is to "harvest" my WFS DescribeFeatureType to populate a filtering menu.

Comment: I have a feeling that OpenLayers 3 (and presumably 4) doesn't support WFS version 2.n so it's not just a supported operation issue.

Comment: Your are right. But my call could also be in version 1.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at jsonix [1] and w3c-schemas [2] instead

```
import {XSD_1_0} from 'w3c-schemas/lib/XSD_1_0';
const xsdContext = new Jsonix.Context([XSD_1_0]);
const xsdUnmarshaller = xsdContext.createUnmarshaller();
var schema = xsdUnmarshaller.unmarshalString(xmlhttp.responseText).value;
var element = schema.complexType[0].complexContent.extension.sequence.element;
```

[1] https://github.com/highsource/jsonix
[2] https://github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas

Comment: Looks interesting, but I can't see how w3c-schemas would help in this instance. WFS doesn't seem to be supported.  Instead wouldn't you have to create your own bespoke jsonix bindings for your own WFS?

Comment: WFS DescribeFeatureType returns an XMLSchema, so you can read it with the XML schema reader just fine

Comment: I will try it soon.

Comment: See here for an example https://github.com/boundlessgeo/sdk/blob/master/src/services/WFSService.js#L122:L165

Comment: An another example based on node https://github.com/highsource/jsonix-support/blob/master/w/wfs-dynamic/tests/wfs-dynamic.js